# Can a char* be moved into an std::string?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, c-strings

Say I have something like this

```
extern "C" void make_foo (char** tgt) {
  *tgt = (char*) malloc(4*sizeof(char));
  strncpy(*tgt, "foo", 4);
}

int main() {
  char* foo;
  make_foo(&foo);
  std::string foos{{foo}};
  free(foo);
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

Now, I would like to avoid using and then deleting the `foo` buffer. I.e., I'd like to change the initialisation of `foos` to something like

```
  std::string foos{{std::move(foo)}};
```

and use no explicit `free`.

Turns out this actually compiles and seems to work, but I have a rather suspicious feel about it: does it actually move the C-defined string and properly free the storage? Or does it just ignore the `std::move` and leak the storage once the `foo` pointer goes out of scope?

It's not that I worry too much about the extra copy, but I do wonder if it's possible to write this in modern move-semantics style.

Comment: It "ignores" the `std::move` (it moves the `const char *`, not the actual data) and leak. You cannot use a predefined buffer with `std::string`

Comment: I think first level of incompatibility is malloc/free in C++

Comment: It's impossible to do what you want (in standard C++).

Comment: @JacekCz what do you mean – I should be using `#include <cstdlib>` and then `std::free`? I certainly can't do anything about the `malloc` in the C code, and why would this be a problem anyway?

Comment: @leftaroundabout They probably meant that even if `std::string` did take ownership it would call the `destroy` for the default allocator which calls `delete` and not `free`. Mixing `delete` with `malloc` is a no-no.

Comment: if you are able, consider [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) (c++17)

Comment: Just for the record, `std::move` doesn't actually move anything, it just performs a cast.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but using `strncpy` here is belt-and-suspenders programming, with broken suspenders. The code allocates an array of 4 `char`, and copies 4 characters into it. Fine, no problem. But if it was modified to copy 5 characters instead, `strncpy` would happily stop copying after the first 4 characters then return, producing an **unterminated** char array. That will almost certainly result in a memory access out of bounds later in the program. `strncpy` is **not** a "safe" replacement for `strcpy` for any reasonable definition of "safe".

Comment: @PeteBecker comment appreciated, I'm rubbish at C programming. (In my actual use case, the string doesn't come from C but from Haskell, through an automatically-generated C interface, so I don't need to worry about that kind of pitfall.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### tl;dr: Not really.

Pointers don't have any special move semantics. `x = std::move(my_char_ptr)` is the same as `x = my_char_ptr`. They are *not* similar in that regard to, say, `std::vector`'s, in which moving takes away the allocated space.

However, in your case, if you want to keep existing heap buffers and treat them as strings - it can't be using `std::string`'s, as they can't be constructed as a wrapper of an existing buffer (and there's small-string optimization etc.). Instead, consider either implementing a custom container, e.g. with some string data buffer (`std::vector<char>`) and an `std::vector<std::string_view>`, whose elements point into that buffer.

Comment: @SombreroChicken: ?

Answer (score 6):

[std::string constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) #5:

> Constructs the string with the contents initialized **with a copy of
>   the null-terminated character string pointed to by s.** The length of
>   the string is determined by the first null character. The behavior is
>   undefined if s does not point at an array of at least
>   Traits::length(s)+1 elements of CharT, including the case when s is a
>   null pointer.

Your C-string is copied (the `std::move` doesn't matter here) and thus it is up to you to call `free` on `foo`.

A `std::string` will never take ownership.

Comment: More fundamental: resolving ownership of char * argument is impossible. Maybe this is nth character of "abcde"+2, maybe on the stack, maybe allocated. Languages hahivng concept of "string owneship" are totally diferent. Opposite illustration from C++ world: smart pointer (aka example of ownership ideo) doesnt have arithmetic, why?